# Manifest v3 content security policy service worker hot reload

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am in the process of converting my manifest two chrome extension to manifest 3. I am proceeding nicely, except for one item that is driving me crazy. That item is a hot reload of the service worker during debugging. I am currently reloading the extension, which is painful for debugging. I have read that setting up a hot reload in the manifest is possible. I have tried several entries in the manifest file, but none had any effect. Could somebody point me in the correct direction? It seems like there is conflicting information all over the web. A sample of a manifest would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Interested too, did you find a way?